# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'execute') command handler

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

```
    const discord = require('discord.js')

const client = new discord.Client({ intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES"] })

const prefix = '&';

const fs = require('fs');

client.commands = new discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log("================");
    console.log("|Bot is ready|");
    console.log("================");
});

client.on('message', message =>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command === 'ip'){
        client.commands.get('ip').execute(message, args);
    } else if (command == 'creator'){
        client.commands.get('creator').execute(message, args);
    } else if (command == 'rulespost'){
        client.commands.get('rulespost').execute(message, args, discord);
    } else if(command == 'test'){
        client.commands.get('test').execute(message, args);
    }
    
})
```

And with this I get an error with 'rulespost' saying `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'execute')`
and within rulespost.js is

```
    module.exports = {
    name: 'RulesPost',
    description: "Posts the rules of the server",
    execute(message, args, discord) {
        const newEmbed = Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#000000')
        .setTitle('Official Rules for ALL Platforms')
        .setDescription('...')
        .addFields(
            {value: 'TEXT'}
        )
        message.channel.send(newEmbed)


    }
}
```

And when using the &rulespost command the bot dies and nothing else happens.
all other commands work fine with no problems but trying to use the embed command it kills the bot completely.

Comment: Have you even defined the commands collection(`client.commands`)? And does it includes `rulepost` command in?

Comment: Notice `"rulespost" != "RulesPost"`. It's a typo

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Note this is WRONG, however it can not be taken down as it is marked for some reason.

the syntax for the *execute* function is incorrect. The interpreter thinks that you are calling a function and then passing further items to the object. this can be fixed by adding the *function* keyword or by assigning *execute* to an anonymous function like so:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'RulesPost',
    description: "Posts the rules of the server",
    // Execute is the key for the anon. function 
    execute: function(message, args, discord) {
        const newEmbed = Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#000000')
        .setTitle('Official Rules for ALL Platforms')
        .setDescription('...')
        .addFields(
            {value: 'TEXT'}
        )
        message.channel.send(newEmbed)
    }
}
```

This creates the execute function that you are exporting.

Comment: Could you link/copy+paste a screenshot to the whole error message? That would help a bit thanks!

Comment: Their syntax is definitely correct. That's how you can assign a function to an object property

Comment: oops! sorry I will take this answer down

Comment: Not sure how this answer got accepted but this is incorrect. :|

Comment: I know sorry, I can't take it down though becuase it's accepted